# Reading binary unsigned short from a file in C++ using ifstream

Tags: c++, c, binaryfiles

I have the following sample code which wrote by C language.
The function of the following code reads the first two bytes from jpg image file.

```
unsigned short buff;
FILE *file;
file = fopen("image.jpg", "rb");
if(file != NULL){
    fread(&buff, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, file);
    fclose(file);
    printf("%X\n", buff);
}else{
    printf("File does not exists.");
}
```

**The result:**
`D8FF`

**That's what I tried to write in C++ :**

```
char fBuff[4];
ifstream file("image.jpg", ios::binary);
if(file.is_open()){
    file.read(fBuff, sizeof(char)*4);
}else{
    cout << "File does not exists." << endl ;
}

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    cout << ios_base::hex << fBuff[i];
```

The problem in the c++ code, it gives me the data incorrectly.

What I want is, change the `fread()` to the appropriate function that corresponding in C++.
But the other functions like `fopen`, `fclose`, `printf`, etc, I know the corresponding in C++.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about language translation services.

Comment: @MartinJames: I want only the corresponding of `fread()` in c++ .

Comment: @LionKing Then leave it as it is. If you are not required to change it, then don't, it will be fine in c++.

Comment: The code is valid (if antiquated) in C++. Why fix things that are not broken? But if ypu wish look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Comment: I want to be able to write one code by using whether C or C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```
std::ifstream  file;
unsigned short buff;

file.open("image.jpg", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (file.is_open() == true)
{
    if (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&buff), sizeof(buff)) != 0)
        std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << buff << std::endl;
    file.close();
} else {
    std::cout << "File does not exists" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you probavly want  `| std::ios::binary` in the file.open

Comment: That's it. the difference in `reinterpret_cast<char *>` the conversion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
istream& read (char* s, streamsize n)

s - Pointer to an array where the extracted characters are stored.
n - Number of characters to extract.


reinterpret_cast<char *> might be needed for some people
```

This reads the file just like fread.

```
istream& get (streambuf& sb, char delim);

istream& getline (char* s, streamsize n );
```

Comment: I have used this function previously, it gives me the data incorrectly.

Comment: @LionKing it wrks fine for everone else: perhaps review this tutorial www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/